# 2-Way SSL (Mutual Authentication) in ASMX and ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, iis, ssl, asmx

I'm researching on how integrate 2-way SSL in two IIS servers

- ASP.Net web site is hosted in one server.
- ASMX web services is hosted in another server.

They both run under Dot Net 3.5 in Windows Server 2003.

I am aware IIS needs to take the follow steps as part of 2-way SSL.

1. Install certificates through Certificates MMC.
2. Configure both web applications to require secured channel SSL.

But I cannot tell what steps need to take in my ASP.Net and ASMX application.

Does IIS handle 2-way SSL internally? (Provided the server is configured correctly)

Do I need custom coding to handle 2-way SSL in my application?

I found plenty of articles reference to WCF setup, which breaks down into two steps

- Setup WCF configuration to use certificate explicitly.
- Setup that certificates to IIS server.

However, I’m not finding anything relevant within ASMX context or within ASP.Net context.

Thanks in advance.